# How to get noitemsep with etaremune?

Tags: etaremune

I have a document with lots of

```
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
   \item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

but want to change that to reverse numbering. Great, the etaremune (funny name ;) ) package does this, but only almost: etaremune doesn't mix with noitemsep:

```
    \begin{etaremune}[noitemsep]
       \item ...
    \end{etaremune}
```

throws the error

```
    ! Package xkeyval Error: `noitemsep' undefined in families `template'.
```

Any suggestions to reduce the itemsep in an etaremune environment?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I figured it out. Use

```
    \begin{etaremune}[itemsep=0pt]
       \item ...
    \end{etaremune}
```